# play framework response doesn't support multiple headers

Tags: java, http-headers, playframework-2.0

I need to add multiple WWW-Authenticate headers (Negotiate, Basic) to a response in play framework 2.3, but it isn't supported at the moment as mentioned [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3544).

Is there a way I can bypass play and get multiple headers?

```
play.mvc.Controller.response().setHeader(Http.HeaderNames.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Negotiate");
play.mvc.Controller.response().setHeader(Http.HeaderNames.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic Realm=\"secure\"");
```

In this case the first header is overridden by the second.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put them in one header:

```
play.mvc.Controller.response().setHeader(Http.HeaderNames.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Negotiate, Basic Realm=\"secure\"");
```

Comment: I already tried that, bit it didn't work. When I put both in one header nothing happens. The browser doesn't do anything.